# Convert string with pipe delimited values to a JSON value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have a `Parameters_A` column in table A which has data like this :

```
Number,3771|ScheduleTime,0.00:00:00|LastData,|DP_AddPaymentDetails_URL,NULL|DP_URL,https://facebook.com
```

I need to move it into `Parameters_B` column in table B with foreign key (`ID_A`) from table A like this:

```
[
   {
      "Name":"Number",
      "Value":"3771"
   },
   {
      "Name":"ScheduleTime",
      "Value":"0.00:00:00"
   },
   {
      "Name":"LastData",
      "Value":""
   },
   {
      "Name":"DP_AddPaymentDetails_URL",
      "Value":"NULL"
   },
   {
      "Name":"DP_URL",
      "Value":"https://facebook.com"
   }
]
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      13.0.16000.28
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      13.0.1700.441
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      10.0.17763.1
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.17763.0
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.42000
Operating System      6.3.17763

Comment: If the values contain no commas, you can replace `|` with `"},{"Name":"` and `,` with `", Value":"`. You'll have to add `[{"Name":"` before the replaced string and `}]` after it to convert it to a valid JSON string

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  `[{"` and `"}]`

Answer (score 0):

JSON is just a string. Assuming the input has no single or double quotes, you can convert it to a JSON string in any SQL Server version. To do so you need to replace :

- `,` with `", "Value":"`
- `|` with `"},{"Name":"`
- Add `[{"Name":"` at the front and
- `"}]` at the end

to get a proper JSON string.

This query :

```
select 
'[{"Name":"' + 
    replace(
        replace('Number,3771|ScheduleTime,0.00:00:00|LastData,|DP_AddPaymentDetails_URL,NULL|DP_URL,https://facebook.com',',','", "Value":"')
        ,'|','"},{"Name":"')
        +'"}]'
```

Produces :

```
[{"Name":"Number", "Value":"3771"},{"Name":"ScheduleTime", "Value":"0.00:00:00"},{"Name":"LastData", "Value":""},{"Name":"DP_AddPaymentDetails_URL", "Value":"NULL"},{"Name":"DP_URL", "Value":"https://facebook.com"}]
```

After formatting :

```
[
 {"Name":"Number", "Value":"3771"},
 {"Name":"ScheduleTime", "Value":"0.00:00:00"},
 {"Name":"LastData", "Value":""},
 {"Name":"DP_AddPaymentDetails_URL", "Value":"NULL"},
 {"Name":"DP_URL", "Value":"https://facebook.com"}
]
```

*Parsing* this to extract individual values though requires SQL Server 2016 and later